# VBA to Filter Data from one workbook, then Paste Results into Another, and Repeat

Tags: excel, vba

I have recorded a macro that does what I want it to do, but it has gotten quite large and unwieldy as the amount of data has increased. The goal is pretty simple: I have one Master Workbook with about 25 sheets. I need to filter about 10 of those sheets, based on the same input, and then copy and paste the data from each sheet of the Master into 10 different sheets on the Active workbook.

I currently have just a recorded Macro, but it uses "Select" in about every line, and I am aware that is nowhere near efficient. I am quite new to VBA, but am interested in improving this code to be quicker and less rigid. Thank you very much to anyone who can provide some advice!

```
`Sheets("AR Tasks (H)").Select
Range("E1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
Range("E1").Select

'Activates Dashboard master, filters tab, and copies data
Windows("Dashboard Macro Master.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("AR Tasks (H)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB$1236").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "PB Charlotte"
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range("A1:AB1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

'Returns to macro worksheet and pastes data'
Windows("Dashboard Pivots Office by Office Master Macro.xlsm").Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("E1").Select
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select`
```

Comment: Are you really stuck on using VBA?  You could probably achieve the same results using Power Query to pull data from the "master" file, and then there's no need for macros at all

Comment: @jpittman power query is the better method as you can query each table and combine them into one and simply refresh the table with a click. Your team may be enamored by VBA, but they will drool when they see how power query handles it.

Comment: Honestly not really sure how Power Query would work exactly in this scenario. I'm needing each tab filtered, then brought in as a new tab. These tabs then all have their own Pivot Tables. The current Macro brings in the fresh data on each tab and refreshes the pivots. The main functionality I'm aware of with Power Query is combining data, how would I get this automatic refresh there?

Comment: I'm a bit dumb today, I can figure this one out. Appreciate the help